# android libgdx mobclix no show

Tags: android, libgdx, mobclix

Please help me figure out why not see ads. tried to run on the emulator and real device. log file from the link below, although it seems nothing useful

https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B6aJ6H5VNJ4XSlNGem84T3EyV1E

```
public class GameActivity extends AndroidApplication {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

      Mobclix.onCreate(this);
      RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(this);

      requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
      getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
                      WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
      getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);


      View gameView = initializeForView(new GraphicsView(), false);
      MobclixAdView adView = new MobclixMMABannerXLAdView(this);
      adView.getAd();
      adView.setRefreshTime(30000);

      RelativeLayout.LayoutParams adParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
      adParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
      adParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);

      layout.addView(gameView);
      layout.addView(adView, adParams);
      setContentView(layout);


    }

     @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
    }
}
```

Comment: We can better assist you if you submit a support ticket. http://support.mobclix.com/tickets/new Thanks,
Michael

Answer (score 0):

Did you include the *Mobclix.jar* in your *libs* folder? If yes, then the banner is not yet available. It is due to random availability of the signal. If there's no signal, it will appeared as question mark. user1385802 was right and should check for your support ticket. It might be.

See http://support.mobclix.com/attachments/token/lvbgrqsfpjgvgxb/?name=Detailed+Start+Guide+for+Android.pdf for more details. ("5. Troubleshooting", page 15)